# PHP cURL multi handling performance slower than normal cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use cURL curl_multi_init() as a means to speed up requests.
What I am experiencing though is that the request with the multi handles initinally take longer than the same request made with curl_init().

Below is an example of two identical requests. **Consistently** the multi request takes about 4/5 times longer than the single request.
The cURL options in both requests are identical. In this example the multi cURL only makes one request.

Additional info: PHP 5.3.3/cURL 7.21.0, Windows server 2008/IIS 7x.

I am totally flabbergasted about what could be causing this slow response. The request is being made to a server which resides in the same network, years of usage of the normal cURL has given me the experience that this kind of request, to this particular backend with non multi handling, take on average between 0.2/0.3 seconds.

The question is: what could be causing this slowness of the multi cURL request.

Below are the results of a test, two requests, one being done with curl_init(), the other with curl_multi_init (both in the same script).
Notice the cURL info, the requests being exactly the same in terms of header_size, request_size, size_upload, size_download and download_content_length.

Test with normal cURL:

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://myurl.com
    [content_type] => text/xml;charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 261
    [request_size] => 312
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.203
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.015
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.015
    [size_upload] => 174
    [size_download] => 236
    [speed_download] => 1162
    [speed_upload] => 857
    [download_content_length] => 236
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.203
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

Test with multi cURL (notice the speed upload/download is lower, connect and name lookup time higher):

```
Array
(
    [client] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://myurl.com
            [content_type] => text/xml;charset=UTF-8
            [http_code] => 200
            [header_size] => 261
            [request_size] => 312
            [filetime] => -1
            [ssl_verify_result] => 0
            [redirect_count] => 0
            [total_time] => 1.047
            [namelookup_time] => 0.61
            [connect_time] => 0.61
            [pretransfer_time] => 0.61
            [size_upload] => 174
            [size_download] => 236
            [speed_download] => 225
            [speed_upload] => 166
            [download_content_length] => 236
            [upload_content_length] => 0
            [starttransfer_time] => 1.047
            [redirect_time] => 0
            [multi_handle_info] => Array
                (
                    [msg] => 1
                    [result] => 0
                    [handle] => Resource id #5
                )

        )

)
```

Example of the code for the multi cURL (options are same as in the code for normal cURL):

```
$curl = array();        
$result = array();      
$mh = curl_multi_init();

foreach (array_keys($queries) as $id) {

    $curl[$id] = curl_init();           
    curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_URL,$queries[$id]['url']); 
    curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,60); 
    curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT,3600); 
    curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 240);      
    curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $queries[$id]['post']);         

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curl[$id]);
}

$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);             
} while($running > 0);

// get content and remove handles
foreach($curl as $id => $c) {

    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);           
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
}
```

Comment: In addition: using IP address instead of a domain name in the option CURLOPT_URL speeds the multi handling up to a max of 0.6 seconds. Still three times slower than non multi handling.

Comment: The critical piece of information missing is: exactly how many parallel requests you're firing?

Comment: @lafor "In this example the multi cURL only makes one request."

Comment: In addition: whether one or ten requests are made with the multi handler, the average time per request remains the same 1.0 to 1.5 seconds.
The curl info given for the multi handler is the info for one handler, as made clear in the array [multi_handle_info].

Comment: @Jaes - I was experimenting with curl_multi, and I noticed the exact same. 1 request takes longer in multi than normal. Have you figured out why, and how to mitigate that? Thanks!